# Spread enum with values of a different enum

Tags: typescript

I am trying to spread a whole enum with a two values of a different enum. The type I get for `lockProspectReasons` is quite weird. The result of the constants should be an array of those reasons as strings. I am trying to type all of these under `LockChangeReason[]` and all succeed except `lockProspectReasons`.

```
 enum LockReason {
  Cancel = 'Cancel',
  Ban = 'Ban',
  CloseAccount = 'CloseAccount',
}

 enum UnlockReason {
  Unban = 'Unban',
}

 enum SharedReason {
  Other = 'Other',
}

// (LockReason | SharedReason.Other)[]
const lockCustomerReasons = Object.values({ ...LockReason, ...SharedReason });
// (SharedReason.Other | UnlockReason.Unban)[]
const unlockCustomerReasons = Object.values({ ...UnlockReason, ...SharedReason });
// WHAT?
const lockProspectReasons = Object.values({
  ...[LockReason.Cancel, LockReason.Ban],
  ...SharedReason,
});

type LockChangeReason = (LockReason | UnlockReason) | SharedReason;
const reason1: LockChangeReason[] = lockCustomerReasons;
const reason2: LockChangeReason[] = unlockCustomerReasons;
const reason3: LockChangeReason[] = lockProspectReasons;
```

Is my syntax wrong? How do I possibly define `lockProspectReasons` so that I get the right result `['Cancel', 'Ban', 'Other']` and the type is not crazy?

[Here's a TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=57&pln=28&pc=1#code/AQUwdgrgtsAyD2BjA1gJRAQwM7zMA3gLABQwwAwhmIiADbAC8wA5JdXcwDQlkBCVjFvzBceFWvCwgAgokTwIYAC6DWEqbPmKlo4gF8SPcNGABVMBJTpsuAmPMAjAU2aOqug8SOQYAZQAWGABOIAAm1jh4RKTAAPJK-iBBqvGJQR6GxAD0WcAAFAhWmJHAAD7AAcFhEbgAdKlJAJQA2gC6JPJgWCqWyOQQ3fBQSTVdgrEOAFYgiEq1AG4YtBAgWHn4wLVbhWjFuJybW5Uh4Xt4eo0A3CQ5%20cfVZ-UJSWVmFki7NmC1bmAt7cROt1gIpev1BsMgqMsOMpjM5otlqt1ocfu8il8DltavdTl9gBdrtlcgB1AAS0gAKgB%20Dq4YG9AAKQUkAAd4dDYdNZgslis1tEyNjmjtRrU2DRaAdRY9hK1uDFsbjRgrCXSuvBaCBahIAOZ5ZhggZKIYjM5YLjAI0Qs1fLBXdU4LU6%20D65igj7gk2Q6GWj0oL2mqHmh2A%20ma7V6g1MllYdmzX0HGNsjkhokkJQAT3ZcE9gTAupAo0EBQ%20xfK5l6o0ar2VZyJQJUIS%20AEYAFy5gP5wujNqCa3e22RLAN%20lNs4AJg7O3I3aLZz7TH9fWNQeho6646%20AGZp3mqD2F61%20x9mSmE%20bLkA)

Comment: Is there a special reason for you to use Object.values? What about: `const lockProspectReasons = [LockReason.Cancel, LockReason.Ban, SharedReason.Other]`?

Comment: If `SharedReason` expands I don't want to add every single element of that enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
const lockProspectReasons = [LockReason.Cancel, LockReason.Ban, ...Object.values(SharedReason)];
```